# Is there a rule for poison gathering?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, skills, familiars, poison

I have heard some people are gathering poison from their Imps (fetched by Improved Familiar feat) and give it to the rogue in their team. But I can't find the related rule anywhere (there's a [Craft (Poisonmaking)] skill but it only covers the poison given as items in the game, not the poison from a creature). Is there any official rule for poison gathering (instead of crafting), like the time consumption and the risk of getting accidentally poisoned?

Comment: [Duplicate-ish.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/105105/8610) Close enough?

Comment: @HeyICanChan Perhaps not that close. I assume a player should not need to either use Handle Animal skill or teach a trick for an Imp that is intelligent enough to do what a human can do (especially as a familiar). Also, it would be best if the related rules can be given here since I don't have Drow of the Underdark in my hand.

Comment: RE: "I have heard some people are gathering poison from their Imps…." Link?

Comment: @HeyICanChan Can't find exactly the link now, but I saw someone said they could cast Bear's Endurance on the imp to improve the poison's DC and then let their rogue use that poison. Possibly homebrew rule, through. I wonder if this tactic is usable in RAW.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't find any exact rules about the time of poison gathering, but I did find [some rules](https://www.realmshelps.net/stores/poison.shtml) on how much time it takes to make venom. You could fold up the poison gathering in the poison making roll. If you really want some rules for poison gathering risk, you could say that on a natural 1, they accidentally get poisoned.

Your players are presumably competent, I don't think they'll get poisoned by the animals that easily.

These are the time rules:

> *Time*: To figure our how much poison can be made in a week, the character makes a Craft (poisonmaking) check at the end of the week. If the check is successful, multiply the check result by the DC for the check. That result is how many gold pieces' worth of poison are created that week. When the total gold pieces' worth created equals or exceeds the market price of one dose of the poison, that poisonmaker has completed that dose. For a skilled poisonmaker, multiple doses in a week may be possible. If the poisonmaker fails the check, no progress is made that week. If the poisonmaker fails the check by 5 or more, the raw materials are ruined and must be reobtained.

Comment: I have seen this rule but just don't want to use it since it is too time-consuming. I guess I would find that *Drow of the Underdark* somewhere on the internet.